WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Server unexpectedly closed network connection || Timeout error
We have a functionality where files are transferring from server1 to SFTP server without any issue. It is using WinScp.exe utility to copy the files.
In other environment, when files are copied from server2 to the same SFTP server , it is throwing an error after 1 or 2 files are being copied. Most likely it seems like a timeout error.
Error: The server rejected SFTP connection, but it listens for FTP connections. Did you want to use FTP protocol instead of SFTP? Prefer using encryption.
Initially, timeout was not set which tends to infinite timeout. Still it is getting timed out. If we provide timeout value explicitly , some where it is overriding and getting timed out.
Same C# code deployed in both servers, but from server2 there is issue for multiple files copy to SFTP server.
Tried setting timeout value from the code.
Timeout value set : sessionOptions.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
Although it is set as above, it is getting timed out before specified value only.
Session Log : Scheduling output: [winscp> open "sftp://ss.com" -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 16:54:6a:ss:" -timeout=300]
Above shows timeout value is being taken as 300 seconds.
[Pinging from server1 to SFTP server]: TTL = 125
[ping statistics from server1] : Statistics_1
[Pinging from server2 to SFTP server ] : TTL=128
Ping statistics from server2 : Statitics_2

SCP and SFTP require synchronization of server and client times. If a very large file is copied, connection might fail because the original handshake was a time back. Double-check the system times on both machines, which should be within a minute of each other.

The error happens when connecting. Are you opening a new connection for every transfer?

yes @MartinPrikryl

@DrMoishePippik, System timings are same.

Then no surprise the server eventually blocks you.

@MartinPrikryl, Same logic is working as expected in other environment.
